# Vue.js Dynamic Input Value Bindings

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

We are trying to automatically generate product slugs from product titles. Those slugs needs to both be editable and also post to the database even if the user chooses not to edit.

For example, a title `"Red Shirt"` generates the slug `"redshirt"`. The user could then either leave the slug as is or edit it to `"redcottonshirt"`.

This `:placeholder="slug"` works correctly. However, `:value="slug"` returns `undefined`.

Is there a way to make the value equal the slug and then also bind that value to the v-model directive?

Here's our code:

```
    <div>Product Name:</div>
            <v-text-field
              label="Example: Tri-Blend Tank Top"
              v-model.lazy="product.title"
              bottom
              required
              solo
              class="mb-2"
             >
            </v-text-field>
            <div v-if="product.title">
            <div>Product Slug (required):</div>
            <v-text-field
              class="mb-2"
              :value="slug"
              :placeholder="slug"
              v-model.lazy="product.slug"
              solo
              required
              >
            </v-text-field>
            </div>
```

And computed property:

```
slug () {
  return this.product.title.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have both `v-model` and `:value` on component. And besides, I don't think v-model on computed property works. Computed properties are getters by default.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your slug into a data attribute:

```
data() {
  return {
    slug: product.title.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
  };
}
```

Doing this you won't have to change anything in your markup.

Comment: this generates console errors: "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined""